# Rails 4.2 ActionController:BadRequest custom error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actioncontroller

I want to return from my controller if either a validation failed or a parameter is missing with `400 - bad request`. So in my controller if have

```
if params["patch"].nil? then
  raise ActionController::BadRequest.new( "The Json body needs to be wrapped inside a \"Patch\" key")
end
```

and i catch this error in my Application Controller with:

```
rescue_from ActionController::BadRequest, with: :bad_request


def bad_request(exception)
  render status: 400, json: {:error => exception.message}.to_json
end
```

But it seems like i cannot add custom messages when raising `ActionController::BadRequest`. Because when passing an invalid body the response is only `{"error":"ActionController::BadRequest"}` and not the hash i provided.

In the console i get the same behaviour.  `raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, "foo"`  indeed raises `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: foo`.

But `raise ActionController::BadRequest, "baa"`  results in

`ActionController::BadRequest: ActionController::BadRequest`

How can i add custom messages to the `BadRequest` exception?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
raise ActionController::BadRequest.new(), "The Json body needs to be wrapped inside a \"Patch\" key"
```